# Owned by group, Owned by user

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, kali-linux, command

I'm doing **Over The Wire challenges**, I didn't understood the meaning of something i.e. ***owned by user and owned by group.***
Thanks for your help:)

Comment: https://www0.sun.ac.za/hpc/images/d/d5/Rute.pdf - see chapters 11 & 14